# Perl Script: SQL commands with IF are displayed as syntax errors

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

SQL commands with IF which are working in MySQL DB are displayed as syntax errors.

```
if (exists(
    SELECT * FROM tanss.leistungen
    where
    firmenid = Tanss
    and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(datum)) >= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 1), INTERVAL MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-6 MONTH), INTERVAL -0 DAY)
    and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(datum)) < DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 1), INTERVAL MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) MONTH), INTERVAL -0 DAY)
) =0 ,"ohne","vorhanden") as Leistung
```

or more simple such as

```
if(niederlassung.name is null,"Niederlassung Warendorf",niederlassung.name) as Niederlassung
```

Error output of cmd is:

> **Bareword found where operator expected** at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 123, near ") =0 ,"ohne"
> (**Might be a runaway multi-line "" string** starting on line 115)
> (**Missing operator before** ohne?)
> **String found where operator expected** at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 123, near "ohne",""
> **Bareword found where operator expected** at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 123, near "","vorhanden"
> (**Missing operator before** vorhanden?)
> **String found where operator expected** at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 123, near "left join tanss.anfahrtpauschale_preise as anfahrtfirma on anfahrtfirma.linkID = vertrag.id and anfahrtfirma.zoneID = ""
> (**Missing semicolon on previous line?**)

or

> **Bareword found where operator expected** at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near "if(niederlassung.name is null,"Niederlassung"
> (**Might be a runaway multi-line "" string** starting on line 111)
> (**Do you need to predeclare if?**)

Im using DBD::ODBC

Is there any way that Perl can accept such extended SQL commands **without** me having to edit it in the script, like im currently doing?

**update:**

- the SQL is a string and the full statement has quotation around it
- the SQL statement is 100% working

**main part of code (but still not full code):**

```
    sub getLeadingMethode{
    $SQL = "
    SELECT
        vertrag.ID as VertragsDBid,
        vertrag.name as Vertragsart,
        vertrag.datumvon as von,
        vertrag.datumbis as bis,
        firmen.displayID as Tanss,
        firmen.name as Kundenname,
    if (exists(
            SELECT * FROM tanss.leistungen
            where
            firmenid = Tanss
            and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(datum)) >= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 1), INTERVAL MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-6 MONTH), INTERVAL -0 DAY)
            and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(datum)) < DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 1), INTERVAL MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) MONTH), INTERVAL -0 DAY)
        ) =0 ,"$4","$5") as Leistung

    FROM tanss.vertrag
        left join tanss.firmen on tanss.firmen.ID = vertrag.firmenID
        left join tanss.anfahrtpauschale_preise as anfahrtfirma on anfahrtfirma.linkID = vertrag.id and anfahrtfirma.zoneID = "$6" and anfahrtfirma.linktypid = "$7"
        left join (select * from tanss.firmen_fahrt as fahrt_1 where km_einfach =(select min(km_einfach) from tanss.firmen_fahrt where firmenID = fahrt_1.firmenid) ) as anfahrt on anfahrt.firmenID = firmen.id
        left join tanss.firmen as niederlassung on niederlassung.id = anfahrt.mandantID
        left join tanss.f_info_werte as vb on vb.firmenid = firmen.id and defID = "$8";";
```

**Full error message:**

```
C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes>sampleCode20.pl
Scalar found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near ") =0 ,"$4"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 100)
        (Missing operator before $4?)
String found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near "$4",""
        (Missing operator before ","?)
Scalar found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near "","$5"
        (Missing operator before $5?)
String found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near "left join tanss.anfahrtpauschale_preise as anfahrtfirma on anfahrtfirma.linkID = vertrag.id and anfahrtfirma.zoneID = ""
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Scalar found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 119, near "left join tanss.anfahrtpauschale_preise as anfahrtfirma on anfahrtfirma.linkID = vertrag.id and anfahrtfirma.zoneID = "$6"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 115)
        (Do you need to predeclare left?)
String found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 119, near "$6" and anfahrtfirma.linktypid = ""
        (Missing operator before " and anfahrtfirma.linktypid = "?)
Scalar found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 119, near "" and anfahrtfirma.linktypid = "$7"
        (Missing operator before $7?)
String found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 119, near "left join tanss.f_info_werte as vb on vb.firmenid = firmen.id and defID = ""
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Scalar found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 122, near "left join tanss.f_info_werte as vb on vb.firmenid = firmen.id and defID = "$8"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 119)
        (Do you need to predeclare left?)
String found where operator expected at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 122, near """
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl line 115, near ") =0 ,"$4"
Execution of C:\Entwicklung\LWEI_SampleCodes\sampleCode20.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: You have no quotes around your SQL statement... that is not Perl code, so it is not recognized by the Perl compiler. You may have other code around it that makes this part make sense, but this is not Perl code.

Comment: That's not valid Perl code. That's SQL. /// Re "*Im using DBD::ODBC*", No, you're are passing the query to `perl` as Perl code to execute.

Comment: ..there are quotes around the statement, i just did not show the complete |  the SQL statement is a string that get passed to databank, so it is perl code and is working at other perl scripts | sql is functioning, i have tested it | im familar with perl but its the first time i have an 'IF' with statements in my SQL which gives me this error | writing the statements as variables seem to not work, because 'IF' is the problem

Comment: @FabulaM24 Your quoting is obviously wrong, so you need to show the whole statement so we can see where it is broken. SQL has nothing to do with Perl errors, that does not take a Perl expert to understand.

Comment: The full statement does not have functioning quotation around it. The errors show it. If you refuse to add more detail, your question cannot be solved and should be closed as "needs details or clarity".

Comment: i have updated my question and shown more of the code | I did not wanted to cause any trouble

Comment: You are quoting the string using `"`, but you have un-escaped double quotes inside the string. For example, around `"$4","$5`. If you escape all the quotes, `\"` your code will work. Or better yet, use a different method of quoting, such as heredocs, or `qq()` or `q()`. Both of those can take different delimiters so accommodate your string, for example `qq# .... #`. You should not interpolate variables in strings if you use DBI, though, you should use placeholders and let the module fix the quoting.

Comment: @TLP i should never have doubted you | unfortunately i am on my way home right now, but the answer looks plausible and so experienced | im going to test it very soon and after im going to accept

Comment: @FabulaM24 Its ok. For your solution, you should probably use placeholders. Interpolating variables can break your code as well, and leave you vulnerable to sql code injection. Also be sure to avoid relying on global variables, encapsulate your code instead by passing arguments to the sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $SQL = "
    .......
        ) =0 ,"$4","$5") as Leistung
```

You have un-escaped double quotes inside a double quoted string. This will break your quotation. You need to escape the quotes, e.g.:

```
    $SQL = "
    .......
        ) =0 ,\"$4\",\"$5\") as Leistung
```

Or use [`qq`/`q`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators)...

```
    $SQL = qq#
    .......
        ) =0 ,"$4","$5") as Leistung
    #
```

Or use a [heredoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#%3C%3CEOF)....

```
    $SQL = <<"END_SQL"
    .......
        ) =0 ,"$4","$5") as Leistung
END_SQL
```

Or if you are using [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), instead of interpolating variables in a string, you should use [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values)

```
    $SQL = "
    .......
        ) =0 , ? , ?) as Leistung
```

And later supply the variables in your execute statement.

```
$dbi->prepare($SQL);        # sample code, not for use
$dbi->execute($4, $5);
```

Also, the variables `$4`, `$5` etc are built-in variables for the regex match capture. It can be dangerous to use them so detached from the regex capture. I assume you are doing something like..

```
if ($foo =~ /(...)(...)..../) {   # capturing $1 .... $7 etc
    getLeadingMethode();          # relying on global scope variables
```

But it would be better to pass the values along with the sub call, like so:

```
if ($foo =~ /(...)(...)..../) {     # capturing $1 .... $7 etc
    getLeadingMethode($4, $5, $7);  # passing values directly, encapsulated approach
```

And like I said above, with DBI you want to use placeholders and let the module handle the quoting.